# Cocos2d - a way to get the current scene?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm looking for a way to get the current scene so that I'll be able to tell which scene is running at any time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check out `CCDirector`. You can get the running scene like this:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene];
```

From the documentation of cocos2D:

> -(CCScene*) runningScene [read, assign]
>
> The current running Scene. Director can only run one Scene at the time

Sandro Meier

Comment: Thanks, How can I compare the runningScene to other scene to check if they are the same?

Comment: guess they are both pointers you can check if two pointer are the same or not!

Comment: Yes do it like Gajet said. Just compare the pointer by using the == operator. if (yourScene == [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene]) {Do something...}

Comment: Thanks, but - 

if ([[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] == [MenuScene scene])
    {
        NSLog(@"MenuScene");
    }




- 
it doesn't work

Comment: Yes that doesn't work. You need to compare with the same instance. If you use [MenuScene scene] you create a new instance and compare with the new one. Compare it directly with the one you create when you presented the scene. ;-)

Comment: First of all thank you for your patience, I will explain my self deeply.
In the applicationWillResignActive, I want to display an pause scene any time the method being called, but, I want to display the pause scene only when the running scene isn't the MenuScene, so I didn't create any instance of MenuScene before.

Comment: No Problem. You're welcome. ;-) In this case you could compare the class. [[[CCDirectory sharedDirector] runningScene] isKindOfClass:[MenuScene class]] So it should work. ;-)